# two setIntervals not activating in a sequence and firing at different times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the flashing effect in a simonGame, and I made these functions to change the colors css to a highlighted color and then back to normal, they take a random sequence from an array and change the colors in the array :

```
game.computerMoves = [green, blue, blue, blue, red, red, yellow];

function showMoves () {

  let i = -1;

  const start = setInterval(function(){
  if(i >= game.computerMoves.length-1){
    clearInterval(start);
  }

  console.log(i + 'start ' + game.computerMoves.length);

  const showColors = new Map([
    [green, 'lime'],
    [yellow, 'rgb(255,255,102)'],
    [blue, 'dodgerblue'],
    [red, 'salmon'],
  ]);

  i++;

  let move = game.computerMoves[i];

  move.style.backgroundColor = showColors.get(move);
 }, 1000);
}

//revert the colors that were changed in showMoves
function removeMoves() {
  let c = -1;
  //put at 2 seconds to change after showMoves is done
  const computerStop = setInterval(function(){

  console.log(c + 'stop ' + game.computerMoves.length);

  if(c >= game.computerMoves.length-1){
     clearInterval(computerStop);

    }
 const colorKey = new Map([
  [green, 'green'],
  [yellow, 'yellow'],
  [red, 'red'],
  [blue, 'blue']
]);

  c++;

  let move = game.computerMoves[c];

   move.style.backgroundColor = colorKey.get(move);
  }, 2000);
}
```

and this function starts both of them:

```
function startFlashing(){
  showMoves();
  removeMoves();
 }
```

I set removeMoves to start every 2 seconds so it can activate after showMoves is finished at 1 second to create a flashing effect, but instead showMoves creates a flashing effect at first, but then showMoves fires a few times faster than removeMoves instead of one after the other and showMoves fires a couple times after showMoves has already looped through the array. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What is `green` etc in `game.computerMoves` ? Where are those variables defined?

Comment: colors : [greenBox = document.getElementById('green'), 
          blueBox = document.getElementById('blue'), 
          yellowBox = document.getElementById('yellow'), 
           redBox = document.getElementById('red')]
       }

Comment: sorry I don't know how to indent code in comments but they represent id's of divs to change colors and are defined there ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine this into one timer that fires every second and then toggles the state accordingly. See below:

```js
const green = 'GREEN';
const blue = 'BLUE';
const red = 'RED';
const yellow = 'YELLOW';
const game = {
  computerMoves: [green, blue, blue, blue, red, red],
};

const move = document.getElementById('move');

const showColors = new Map([
  [green, 'lime'],
  [yellow, 'rgb(255,255,102)'],
  [blue, 'dodgerblue'],
  [red, 'salmon'],
]);

const hideColors = new Map([
  [green, 'green'],
  [yellow, 'yellow'],
  [red, 'red'],
  [blue, 'blue'],
]);

const startFlashing = () => {
  let i = -1;
  let visible = true;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (visible) {
      i += 1;
    }

    if (i >= game.computerMoves.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }

    visible = !visible;
    colorMapper = visible ? showColors : hideColors;
    const turn = game.computerMoves[i];
    const color = colorMapper.get(turn);
    console.log(`visible: ${visible}, color: ${turn}`);
    move.style.backgroundColor = color;
    
  }, 1000);
}

startFlashing();
```

```css
#move {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="move"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this way you can achieve this Use `setTimeout` for second condition which will call from first condition (`setInterval`)

```
game.computerMoves = [green, blue, blue, blue, red, red, yellow];


function showMoves() {

    let i = -1;
    let c = -1;

    const start = setInterval(function() {
        if (i >= game.computerMoves.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(start);
        }

        console.log(i + 'start ' + game.computerMoves.length);

        const showColors = new Map([
            [green, 'lime'],
            [yellow, 'rgb(255,255,102)'],
            [blue, 'dodgerblue'],
            [red, 'salmon'],
        ]);

        i++;

        let move = game.computerMoves[i];

        move.style.backgroundColor = showColors.get(move);
        //revert the colors that were changed in showMoves
        //put at 2 seconds to change after showMoves is done
        const computerStop = setTimeout(function() {

            console.log(c + 'stop ' + game.computerMoves.length);

            if (c >= game.computerMoves.length - 1) {
                clearInterval(computerStop);

            }
            const colorKey = new Map([
                [green, 'green'],
                [yellow, 'yellow'],
                [red, 'red'],
                [blue, 'blue']
            ]);

            c++;

            let move = game.computerMoves[c];

            move.style.backgroundColor = colorKey.get(move);
        }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
}
```

You can separate `setTimeout` code in other function but you need to declare  `c` variable global.